# How to create a new Patchset in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-commit, git-amend

I am new to Gerrit and want to create a new Patch when new changes are submitted. I setup Gerrit with this guide https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/install-quick.html

Then I try to create a new patch with http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/user-changeid.html and also added `Change-Id` line at bottom of the Commit-message.

But I am getting new Change instead of new Patchset. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Step 1**: Install commit-msg hooks for gerrit

```
scp -p -P 29418 <gerrit_url>:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
```

**Step 2**: Create normal commit and push (for Patchset1)

for example:

```
git add Server.java
git commit -m "server added"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

**Step 3**: After doing some changes to Server.java

Finally to create new Patchset (Patchset 2)

```
git add Server.java
git commit --amend
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Repeat step 3 for further Patches

Comment: A note for anyone else potentially confused - this literally means you should push to `refs/for/master`. That isn't a placeholder for some remote branch name you have to figure out - it's actually the remote branch name gerrit expects

Comment: Shouldn't you install the `commit-msg` hook *first*?  With these steps,the initial commit pushed to gerrit won't have a change-id.

Comment: Is there any way to do same thing in GitHub?

Comment: AFAIK, GitHub uses different code review approach. Just push using normal commands and create a pull request. So you don't need to set up anything extra.

Answer (score 4):

Don't add the *Change-Id* on your own. Install the commit-msg hook as described [here](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.0/user-changeid.html#creation). This will automatically create the *Change-Id* for you.

If you want to improve a patch by uploading a new patch-set, use `git-commit --amend` and *keep* the *Change-Id* line as it is.

You can see a description of the workflow here: http://wiki.typo3.org/Contribution_Walkthrough_with_CommandLine

Answer (score 2):

Even if you add Change id manually it should be last paragraph of your commit message. 
And the syntax should be :

```
change ID : [change ID ]
```