# How to add descption to a given patchset in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I can [create new patchset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118947/how-to-create-a-new-patchset-in-gerrit) to a given Gerrit without issues.

However, I would like to describe what the patchset is about. I have been doing that as part of the commit message, as I commit -amend and push the new patchset with the revised comment.

Is there a well defined way of describing the patchset in the commit message, so Gerrit can automatically set its description? The only mentioning of the description I found so far was from this page:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/concept-patch-sets.html#_description

Answer (score 0):

Heh, looks like I found a potential answer for my own question. :)

If I encode the push command with a `%m=` I seem to be able to set the description for the patchset. It feels a little hacky, in that I need to replace
spaces with `_` and percent encode characters as well.

That is described [gerrit's documentation for code review](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.16.2/user-upload.html#message).

Example:

```
git push ssh://john.doe@git.example.com:29418/kernel/common HEAD:refs/for/experimental%m=This_is_a_rebase_on_master%21
```

Any other/better way that you may know about?

Comment: You're not setting a description to the patchset but actually you're adding a comment to the change. I think this is enough for what you want. You can do the same using the Gerrit Web UI.

Comment: In the newer documentation, the same text and command is now available under the heading "patch set description", so I guess this is what was requested in the question: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#patch_set_description