# How to add patchset description without using gerrit ui

Tags: git, command-line, push, gerrit

I would like to add a patch-set description from the git command line.
Ideally it would happen at the same line with the push (similar to [other modifiers](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.16.2/user-upload.html#_git_push) Gerrit has for the push command).

I couldn't find such an option and wondered what I am missing.

An example of what I had in mind:

```
git push ssh://user@gerrit:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/main --patchset-description "This is my description"
```

Comment: It does not seem possible - the closest thing I could find was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057456/how-to-add-descption-to-a-given-patchset-in-gerrit, so either use that or write a plugin for it.

Comment: Thanks! I found that questions as well. However, OP wanted to get the whole change comment. I was wondering if it was possible to do it for a patch-set.